# Retrieving Root Mean Square Error for each regression model in a dataframe

Tags: r, time-series, regression, diagnostics

I have created a model shown here for daily data:

```
myts <- ts(data[2], frequency = 7)
fit <- auto.arima(myts)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Series: myts 
ARIMA(2,1,1)(2,0,0)[7]                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1    sar1    sar2
      0.2874  -0.0422  -0.9349  0.0015  0.1397
s.e.  0.0586   0.0598   0.0293  0.0546  0.0812

sigma^2 estimated as 39.71:  log likelihood=-1188.2
AIC=2388.4   AICc=2388.63   BIC=2411.8

Training set error measures:
                     ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE         ACF1
Training set -0.1423045 6.250017 3.605002 -2.910684 11.96048 0.7200852 -0.000295024
```

How do I obtain a dataframe of just the training set error measures.

In the end, let's say I have 5 different models, I want the final output to look like this dataframe:

```
                  Model Type         RMSE
      ARIMA(2,1,1)(2,0,0)[7]         6.25
Regression with ARIMA(0,0,1)     6.054298
                  ETS(M,N,M)     6.647029
Regression with ARIMA(1,0,0)     5.993514
Regression with ARIMA(1,1,1)     6.135232
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `accuracy` function. Then extract the value from the RMSE to build your data.frame. Without a working example it's hard to give more of an answer.

```
> accuracy(fit)
                    ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set 0.3035616 3.113754 2.405275 0.2805566 1.917463 0.5315228 -0.01715517

> accuracy(fit)[2]
[1] 3.113754
```

Comment: Thank you for your post! Is it possible to get `RMSE` usign `attr` or by name?

Comment: Sure. You just need to extract the first row of the matrix returned by the `accuracy` function and then extract by name. A couple options:

`val <- forecast::accuracy(fit)`     
`val[which(names(val[1,]) == "RMSE")]`
`as.list(val[1,])$RMSE`